# Using window.open equivalent in firefox causes ,NET session variables to go away. Why? How can I fix?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, firefox, apache-flex, session-cookies

I have an application which runs in Adobe/Apache Flex with a .NET middle tier.

To run reports I need them to run in a separate window so I use;

```
navigateToURL(url, "_blank");
```

This works swimmingly in all browsers (IE, Chrome & Edge) except Firefox (FF). The app has been around for quite a while, and I can't imagine that it never worked in FF, but it doesn't with the last couple of releases.

The symptom is that the .NET "Current.Session.SessionID" changes to a new ID for both the original browser window as well as the new browser window. This causes it to lose all session variables, of course.

The problem only seems to manifest itself if I use "POST" to send variables to the popup window. If I use "GET" everything works fine. An added "bonus" is the "Post" parameters being sent to the new window disappear. So my report doesn't run, and the original window "loses its mind since the session ID changes."

As a test I dusted the cobwebs off and created two ASPX pages which did

```
 <form method="post" name="TestForm" action="TestWopen2.aspx" target="_blank">
```

The problem was not exhibited in that environment on any browser including FF.

This leads me to believe that Adobe Flex (Flash) is mucking things up a bit.

Comment: Have you tried it in Firefox on another computer, just in case it is something specific to one copy of FF? Setting up a [ready-made virtual machine](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/virtual-machines) to try an [earlier version of FF](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/install-older-version-of-firefox) could be an easy way of doing that.

Comment: Is `url` relative or absolute? Does it happen to change between http: and https:?

Comment: I have tried it on multiple client (Firefox) computers as well as multiple server (IIS) computers We have two development environments as well as production. The two client computers include two W7 and one W10 all using FF 72.0.1 64 bit.

Comment: I build an absolute url before the navigateToURL(url, "_blank");

Comment: Just an idea, but as it looks like you don't want to use GET, would using cookies be a useable alternative?

Comment: This is a large application, with a number of calls for reports and other items which open in new windows. So I would prefer to find what the issue is with FF instead of just implementing a work around.

Comment: could you use Fiddler to compare the request of the new window between FF and chrome